# Showing $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}+\frac{2^{n+1}}{\prod\left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)}\ge n+2$, for $n\geq2$ and for positive real $x_i$

Tags: inequality

Let $n\ge 2$ and $x_1,...,x_n$ are positive real numbers. Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}+\frac{2^{n+1}}{\prod \left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)}\ge n+2$$

Maybe the simplest thing you can do is to note that since $$\sum \frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\ge n$$
We only need to prove $$\prod\left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)\le 2^{n}$$
But using AM-GM we find $$\prod\left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)=\prod\left(\frac{x_i+x_{i+1}}{x_{i+1}}\right)\ge 2^n\prod{\sqrt{\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}}}=2^n$$
I tried to clear denominators,

$$\prod\left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)\left(n+2-\sum \frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)\le 2^{n+1}$$
So we can assume $$\sum \frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\le n+2$$
Otherwise there is nothing to prove. What should I now?

Comment: Hint: add $n$ to both sides, rewrite LHS as a sum of $n+1$ terms and apply AM $\ge$ GM.

Comment: In the original inequality? @achillehui

Comment: Yup. in original inequality.

Comment: What should I do to the product? @achillehui

Comment: the product is the $n+1$-th term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}=nx.$

Thus, by AM-GM twice we obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}+\frac{2^{n+1}}{\prod\left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)}\geq nx+\frac{2^{n+1}}{\left(\frac{n+nx}{n}\right)^n}=n(x+1)+\frac{2}{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n}-n=$$
$$=2\left(n\cdot\frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n}\right)-n\geq2(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n}}-n=$$
$$=2(n+1)-n=n+2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding $n$ to both sides, $$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}+1\right)+\frac{2^{n+1}}{\prod \left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)}\ge 2(n+1)$$

Now we can think of the LHS as a sum of $n+1$ terms, $$
\left(\frac{x_1}{x_{2}}+1\right)+...+\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{1}}+1\right)+\frac{2^{n+1}}{\prod \left(1+\frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}}\right)}\\ \ge n+1\sqrt[n+1]{2^{n+1}\left(\frac{x_1}{x_{2}}+1\right)...\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{1}}+1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{x_1}{x_{2}}+1\right)^{-1}...\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{1}}+1\right)^{-1}} \\ $$

$$=2(n+1)$$